# NHibernate Query slows other queries

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, nhibernate, ssms

i'm writing a program in which i use two database queries using NHibernate. First query is a large one - select with two joins (the big SELECT query) whose result is about 50000 records. Query takes about 30 secs. Next step in the program is iterating through these 50000 record and invoking query on each of this records. This query is pretty small COUNT method.

There are two interesting things tough:

1. If i run the small COUNT query before the big SELECT, the COUNT query takes about 10ms, but if i ran it after the big SELECT query it takes 8-9 seconds. Furthermore, if i reduce the complexity of the big SELECT query i also reduce the time of the COUNT query execution afterwards.
2. If i ran the the big SELECT query on sql server management studio it takes 1 sec, but from ASP.NET application it takes 30 secs.

SO there are two main questions. Why is the query taking so long to execute in code when its so fast in ssms? Why is the big SELECT query affecting the small COUNT queries afterwards.

I know there are many possible answers to this problem but i have googled a lot and this is what i have tried:

1. Setting the SET parameters of asp.net application and ssms so they are the same to avoid different query plans
2. Clearing the ssms cache so the good ssms result is not caused by ssms caching - same 1 second result after the cache clear

The big SELECT query:

```
 var subjects = Query
            .FetchMany(x => x.Registrations)
            .FetchMany(x => x.Aliases)
            .Where(x => x.InvalidationDate == null)
            .ToList();
```

The small COUNT query:

```
Query.Count(x => debtorIRNs.Contains(x.DebtorIRN.CodIRN) && x.CurrentAmount > 0 && !x.ArchivationDate.HasValue && x.InvalidationDate == null);
```

Comment: What is the query that is being produced?  Grab that and run it in SSMS.  FetchMany might be a performance killer here.  why do you have the FetchMany's on the query to begin with?  Is doesn't look like the count query is using any information from it.

Comment: this is just a fraction of a code, the FetchMany data are being used later in the application and are neccesary. Query produced by NHibernate from the code fragment above is pretty big, but i have traced it in the management studio profiler and ran it in the SSMS and it took 1 sec

Comment: then it's probably that your query is re-hydrating so many objects.  that's going to take a long time.  I would remove the FetchMany's until you actually need them and add a projection so that you are only returning the data you need instead of creating entire object hierachies

Comment: if i understand you correctly, i should run the query without fetchmany's. than i can run fetchmany's when needed the additional data right? still, i dont understand the projection part. what is the projection ? how can i use it here?

Comment: So in your "big SELECT query" you don't have a .Select(x=> new someojbect {}).  That is the projection.  If you don't have projection, it will create your entire entity object, plus any objects per the rules in your mapping file.

Comment: Ok, so i tried removing the FatchMany's and of course the query execution time decreased dramatically. i was unable to make the projection you suggested as i would have to specify all the parameters i want in the curly braces ( x=> new MyObject { here}). Another thing i forgot about were the logs of the application. I am using Log4net logger and turning it off before the queries and turning it on after reduced the time to the half... so to sum it up: turning of logs -> big query from 25 secs to 14 sec, small query -> from 8 sec to 4 sec. Deleting FatchMany;s -> big query from 14 sec to 4 sec

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out the above mentioned FatchMany's were inevitable for the program so i couldn't just skip. The first significant improvement i achieved was turning off the loggs of the application (as i mentioned the above code is just a fragment). Performance without logs were about a half faster. But still it took considerable amount of time. SO i decided to avoid using NHibernate for this query and wrote plain sqlQuery to data reader, which i than parsed into my object's. I was able to reduce the execution time from 2.5 days (50000 * 4 sec -> number of small queries * former execution time of one small query) to 8 minutes.